LiveData test fails: Expected MyState$Success, but got null in ViewModel test with coroutines
Problem Description:
I was expecting the LiveData value to be MyState$Success when the test starts, but the value is already set to null.
Questions:
Is the LiveData emitting its value asynchronously and causing this mismatch?
Should I use a different testing strategy to handle LiveData updates in coroutines?
How can I ensure the test waits until the final state (MyState.Success) is emitted?
Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!
Expected :com.br.testesunitarios.ui.MyState$Success@62fad19
Actual   :null
Here is my ViewModel implementation
package com.br.testesunitarios.ui.home

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.br.testesunitarios.ui.MyState
import com.br.testesunitarios.ui.ProviderUseCase
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _state: MutableLiveData<MyState> = MutableLiveData()
    val state: LiveData<MyState> = _state

    fun interactor(interactor: String) {
        when (interactor) {
            "AnyInteractor" -> {
                executarMetodo()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun executarMetodo() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _state.value = MyState.Loading
                delay(1000)
                _state.value = MyState.Success
                delay(1000)
                when (ProviderUseCase().execute()) {
                    MyState.Success -> {
                        _state.value = MyState.Success
                    }
                    else -> {
                        _state.value = MyState.Failure
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _state.value = MyState.Failure
            }
        }
    }
}

This is my test case, using StandardTestDispatcher and runTest:
package com.br.testesunitarios.ui.home

import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import com.br.testesunitarios.ui.MyState
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.StandardTestDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.resetMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class HomeViewModelTest {

    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun `should execute executarMetodo when interactor is AnyInteractor`() = runTest {
        val viewModel = HomeViewModel()

        viewModel.interactor("AnyInteractor")

        assertEquals(MyState.Success, viewModel.state.value)  // This line fails
    }
}

Gradle setup:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.br.testesunitarios"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.br.testesunitarios"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)
    testImplementation(libs.junit.jupiter)
    testImplementation(libs.mockito.core)
    testImplementation(libs.mockito.kotlin)
    testImplementation(libs.mockito.jupiter)
    testImplementation(libs.coroutines.test)
    testImplementation(libs.arc.core.testing)
    testImplementation (libs.junit.jupiter.api) 
    testRuntimeOnly(libs.junit.jupiter.engine)




    testImplementation(libs.io.mockk)

    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform() 
}

And LibVersions
[versions]
agp = "8.6.1"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.15.0"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.12.0"
constraintlayout = "2.2.0"
lifecycleLivedataKtx = "2.8.7"
lifecycleViewmodelKtx = "2.8.7"
navigationFragmentKtx = "2.8.5"
navigationUiKtx = "2.8.5"
junitJupiter = "5.11.3"

mockitoCore = "5.7.0"
mockitoKotlin = "5.2.0"
mockitoJupiter = "5.7.0"
coroutinesTest = "1.7.3"
arcCoreTesting = "2.2.0"
ioMockk = "1.13.5"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
junit-jupiter-api = { group = "org.junit.jupiter", name = "junit-jupiter-api", version.ref = "junitJupiter" }
junit-jupiter-engine = { group = "org.junit.jupiter",  name = "junit-jupiter-engine", version.ref = "junitJupiter" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
androidx-lifecycle-livedata-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-livedata-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleLivedataKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodelKtx" }
androidx-navigation-fragment-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-navigation-ui-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navigationUiKtx" }
junit-jupiter = { group = "org.junit.jupiter", name = "junit-jupiter", version.ref = "junitJupiter" }


mockito-core = { group = "org.mockito", name = "mockito-core", version.ref = "mockitoCore" }
mockito-kotlin = { group = "org.mockito.kotlin", name = "mockito-kotlin", version.ref = "mockitoKotlin" }
mockito-jupiter = { group = "org.mockito", name = "mockito-junit-jupiter", version.ref = "mockitoJupiter" }
coroutines-test = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx", name = "kotlinx-coroutines-test", version.ref = "coroutinesTest" }
arc-core-testing = { group = "androidx.arch.core", name = "core-testing", version.ref = "arcCoreTesting" }
io-mockk = { group = "io.mockk", name = "mockk", version.ref = "ioMockk" }


[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" 
}


Also, you forgot an advanceUntilIdle() after viewModel.interactor("AnyInteractor").

@tyg, Thank you for the help! I hadn’t found that link, and adding the class mentioned in the answer indeed solved my issue. I really appreciate your assistance!
